# How can I remove algae in my veg garden?

Tags: algae

Is there something that I can I add to my Vegetable Garden to stop algae? I have not tried anything yet but I know that too much water and lots of sunlight are causes.

Comment: ...add less water and/or fertilizer? I can't imagine much odds than an algaecide to kill that plant would not be harmful to the plants you presumably want to grow. Excess phosphorus is one thing that makes algae grow well, which would be from fertilizer runoff, typically.

Comment: If you have actual algae growing on your soil (as opposed to moss or liverwort) then you are over-watering or you live in an area that is constantly wet and humid. If the latter, there's not much you can do about it. I suppose it's also possible that your soil is incredibly compacted (if you live in England, I'd bet on that) which, when coupled with lots of rain and little sun could grow algae. If this is the case, wait for a dry period and try aerating your soil.

Comment: A picture might help. Just to be sure that it is algae.

Comment: One thing that might be similar (but is not actually an algae) here: https://gardening.stackexchange.com/q/63560/6806