# Need help identifying strange slimy substance spreading on my lawn

Tags: lawn, fungus, lawn-repair

I'm curious what is this slime mass that started out just at one or two places, now is covering ±10 square feet of my lawn?

My ideas are:

- some kind of fungus?
- animal dirt - but unclear what animal?

And the most important question is: how do I stop it spreading (ideally without using heavy chemicals)?

[image: close picture 1]

[image: close picture 2]

[image: close picture 3]

[image: distant picture]

Comment: Slime mould? Try googling "UK lawn slime mould".

Comment: Duplicate - it's a cyanobacterium. https://gardening.stackexchange.com/q/63560/6806